# Бот для вк с командой для вики

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь сделать вк бота который на команду /search (ваш запрос) выводил информацию из вики, вот код:

```py
import vk_api  
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType  
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id  
from wikipedia import wikipedia  

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="64d7f2fcf14c58061752500f4afff07506924f1a9b192e4f5c6596e5c28bfdb86f2212fb4ef8fd28a9b06")  

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)  
session_api = vk_session.get_api()  

wikipedia.set_lang("ru")  


def sendMessage(user_id, text):        
vk.message.send(       
        random_id = get_random_id(),  
        user_id = user_id,  
        message = text,)  


for event in longpoll.listen():  
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:  
        peer_id = event.peer_id  
        cmd = str(event.text).split(" ")  
        if cmd[0] == '/search':  
            try:  
                to_find = str(event.text).replace(cmd[0] + " ", "")  
                res = wikipedia.page(to_find)  
                to_len = len(res.content) + 180 - len(res.content)  
                message = res.title + "\n\n" + res.content[:to_len] + "\nПодробнее: " + res.url  
                sendMessage(peer_id, message)  
            except NameError:  
                sendMessage(peer_id, "Использование: /search <Запрос>")  
            except IndexError:  
                sendMessage(peer_id, "Использование: /search <Запрос>")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @user:400096 спасибо огромное, надеюсь сейчас возможно

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку vk, а не vk_api